# In this properties(ng-repeat) variable is over lapping when i scroll the page ends?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, node.js

I want to send the limit and offset values from client side(angularjs) to nodejs.so
i tried with static values.

my html code :

```
 <div class="prprt-list-ctr row" id="viewpage">
        <div class="hmpal-prprt-wdgt clearfix"  ng-repeat="project in properties"  scroll-trigger="loadMoreRecords()">
            <div class="hmpal-prprt-img">
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

In this properties(ng-repeat) variable is over lapping when i scroll the page ends . This loadMoreRecords() functions when the page scrolls to end.

my directive is scroll-trigger

```
sidemenu.directive('scrollTrigger', function() {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
             angular.element(document).bind('scroll', function() {
                if (jQuery(document).height() <= jQuery(window).scrollTop() +jQuery(window).height()) {
                    scope.$apply(attrs.scrollTrigger);
                }

            });
        }
    };
});
```

my controller code:

```
  sidemenu.controller('buildersCtrl', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$location', '$http', 'allServices','$document','PropertyDetails','$routeParams','$window','typeServices', function (a, b, c, d, e,f,h,r,w,t) {


     var paging={start:0,rows:15}
    e.projectListing(r,paging).then(function (result) {
        a.properties = result.data.items;
        b.closeid = r.id;

    }, function (error) {

    });

    a.loadMoreRecords = function() {
alert("sss");
        var offset=paging.start+paging.rows;
       paging={start:offset,rows:15};
        e.projectListing(r,paging).then(function (result) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
            a.properties = result.data.items;
            b.closeid = r.id;
         }, function (error) {

        });
}
    }})
```